# How to exclude subfolder of DCIM folder (DCIM/SUBFOLDER) from auto syncing in Google Photos app for Android?

Tags: google-photos

[Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos) fully auto syncs DCIM folder of Android (including all its subfolders) and I can't find a way to select only specific subfolders inside DCIM folder to be synced

I have Screenshots subfolder, subfolders from other apps and so on and I don't want them to be synced.

I want to auto sync only DCIM/Camera and that's all.

I can only disable auto sync for the whole DCIM folder, and absurd fact that in the Google Photos app "DCIM" folder is shown as "CAMERA" folder, so basically it ignores any structure inside DCIM folder and just uses the same logic for all files inside DCIM and inside its subfolders as for one category